# How to access motion sensor on Sony NSZ-GS7 Google TV

Tags: google-tv

Sonys website of the NSZ-GS7 devices says "There's also a 3-Axis motion sensor for gaming." in the description of the controller.
http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&productId=8198552921666462151

But when I ask the SensorManager for a list of sensors like on any other android device,  there are none. Do I miss something here?

Sadly, the google page on Google TV supported features tells me that no sensors are supported, too.
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_features#Hardware

So, any idea whats going on here? Is the Sony website lying? Or is there a motion sensor inside this device but not exposed by the OS? whats the point of a sensor you can't use, then? Will it work in future Google TV versions?
Sony support seems not to like me, as they answered none of this quaestions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony developed proprietary API's for their devices to allow developers to get access to sensor data from their physical remotes or the Sony MediaRemote app. You need to integrate their libraries into your app to get to use these API's. Sony has a developer web site with more information: https://android.developer.sony.com/pages/documents/view/?id=4000080

Just be aware that other Google TV devices do not support these API's.